# Checking if 20 random booleans have the same value

Tags: java, random, boolean, probability

I am trying to generate 20 random booleans and see if they have the same value i.e. either all true or all false. I expected the program to run for a while as the probability should be `1/(2^20) *100 * 2`, which is something like 0.00019%.

However, I run my program (shown below) and it terminated extremely quickly, sometimes even take 1 loop. Is there something wrong in my program, or with my logic?

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO; 

    Random rand = new Random();

    while (true) {
        bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        System.out.println(bi);

        boolean x = rand.nextBoolean();
        if (x == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            == rand.nextBoolean() == rand.nextBoolean()
            ) {

            System.out.print(x);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your condition does not do what you think. It will give true with 50% probability.

Comment: Because your test is not what you think... a == b == c doesn't means a equals to b equals to c. Read about operators precedence in Java

Comment: Hint: to express multiple conditions that all need to be true, you should use the `&&` operator. `if (x == rand.nextBoolean() && x == rand.nextBoolean() && x == rand.nextBoolean())` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and hints. The problem is actually simple. Imagine `x` = true and the first random boolean is false. The first `x == rand.nextBoolean()` will be evaluated to false. But instead of terminating to loop, it will continue to evaluate the condition by doing `false == next_random_bool`.

The correct program should be: (surprisingly, it takes around 1 million loops only...)

```
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO; 

    Random rand = new Random();

    while (true) {
        bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE);

        boolean x = rand.nextBoolean();
        if (x == rand.nextBoolean()
            && x == rand.nextBoolean()
            && x == rand.nextBoolean()
            && x == rand.nextBoolean()
            && x == rand.nextBoolean()
            ...
            ) {

            System.out.println(bi);
            System.out.print(x);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: One million is not really surprising, the expectation value is 2^19 = 524288

Comment: Would fit into an int. BigInteger seems a bit pessimistic. :)

Comment: @Lore, `true == false == false` evaluates to `true` (which the original question didn't expect). It breaks down to `step1 = true == false; // evaluates false`, then the last term: `step1 == false` which is then `true`, despite the terms **not** all being equal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe such a loop is useful, in demonstrating, what happens - you don't need to evaluate 10 expressions, but 2 might be too few:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        boolean x = rand.nextBoolean ();
        boolean y = rand.nextBoolean ();
        boolean z = rand.nextBoolean ();

        System.out.println ("values: " + x + " " + y + " " + z);
        if (x == y == z) {
            System.out.println ("        ^ hit");
        }
    }
}
```